# Java и активные процессы

Tags: java

Добрый день.
Возник такой вопрос: есть ли в java библиотека работающая с активными процессами.
Например я мог бы выбрать процес и получить путь к его ехе-файлу
Что то вреде этого

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать тасклист, как [тут](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0593.html).

Comment: В принципе, путь там вроде не показывается. Но с этими данными, по-моему, можно что-то сделать. Надо просто еще в винде покапаться.

Answer (score 0):

В Java нет такой библиотеки. Обычно ограничиваются вызовом ps для Linux/Unix и tasklist.exe для Windows через `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`, а затем парсят результат.